# Get recent file in S3 bucket using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a use case at work that requires a method to find the most recent digital signature certificate. Is there a way to get the last modified file / object from a S3 bucket using the AWS.SDK in .NET CORE 5.0 with C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You will need to retrieve all objects and then use code in your C# program to find the returned object with the latest `LastModifiedDate`.